# Rendering a View as an image in SwiftUI project

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, uikit, render

I am currently handling an end-to-end SwiftUI project which involves a ClockKit complication. As one of complication's templates requires an image (UIImage) I need to render (snapshot) an existing SwiftUI View to an image. I have found a couple of possible solutions to this problem, including the following View extension:

```
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view

        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)

        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that wherever I implement this extension I keep getting "not in scope" Xcode errors (*"Cannot find 'UIHostingController' in scope", "Cannot find 'UIGraphicsImageRenderer' in scope", "Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'clear'"*).

SwiftUI and UIKit are imported in these Swift files (but I think the latter shouldn't be necessary). Xcode 12.5.

Please do share some tips that could help overcome this hurdle... I am a rather inexperienced developer and I could be missing something rather obvious, but at this point I'm pulling my hair out. Whenever I implement a reasonable solution that happened to be in other questions or websites it always comes to UIKit specific commands not being in scope.

**Edit**: So it turns out this extension works only if implemented in main ContentView for iOS target. Does not work if put in any other directory. However I need this extension to work in files of (watchOS) Extension files (as I said it's needed for CK Complication) and it's not possible to set target membership of the main iOS ContentView also for (watchOS) Extension, as then two ContentViews would apply to one watchOS version and error occurs. How then effectively place the above extension code so it could apply for where it's needed?

Comment: You must also `import SwiftUI` (UIHostingController is from SwiftUI)

Comment: @aheze yes yes, SwiftUI was imported obviously, forgot to mention :)

Comment: Interesting... worked fine for me. [screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/Screen%20Shot%202021-04-30%20at%2010.14.46%20AM.png) - check your highlighting compared to my code. You might have defined a custom class that had the same name as a system class.

Comment: @aheze [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/131O9.png) - this is my screenshot. The situation occurs anywhere in Xcode now. And I don't see any custom class named likewise

Comment: Try `Command` + `Shift` + `K`, restart Xcode, go take a walk and come back...

Comment: @aheze Doesn't seem to help either. ‍♂️  Issue appears in this or even a new project. Maybe I should reinstall Xcode again? I just had done it when updating from 12.4 to 12.5

Comment: I'm on 12.5 too. I uploaded [my repo](https://github.com/aheze/UIHostingController-Snapshot) - try it out and see if it compiles.

Comment: @aheze Your repo works. Turns out that this extension also works in my project - but only when inserted in main iOS ContentView. It does not work when inserted in any other file or in (watchOS) Extension's ContentView. One cannot select target membership in iOS ContentView because there's an error that there can only be one ContentView 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for the errors pop up (like *Cannot find UIHostingController in scope* and others) is because `UIHostingController` and `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` are not available on watchOS, meaning the extension, as written, will not compile on that platform.

Refer to [my other answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67419963/swiftui-extension-definition-placement-in-code).