# SwiftUI - Extension definition placement in code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

Xcode is recently giving me a lot of headaches with using an extension that converts a SwiftUI View to an UIImage. The project is predominantly SwiftUI universal app. I need UIImage for ClockKit Complications definitions and I have found the following code that should in theory do that just fine:

```
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view

        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)

        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

The problems are:

1. Xcode allows only the extension to be put at the top of main ContentView, which is not detected by watchOS Extension (as it has its own ContentView and it cannot be shared or set as Target Member for both). In any other place in code I get [the following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEG8o.png).
2. Even if the extension doesn't give en error in the main ContentView then the constant declaration doesn't work either way and it gives [a following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GReRX.png). If that is changed to `let exportimage: UIImage = MoonView.snapshot(MoonView)` it then just says *Cannot convert value of type 'MoonView.Type' to expected argument type 'MoonView'*.

How can one approach the problem? Is it a problem where the extension can be placed? Xcode version 12.5, I cleaned build folder and I can't find any similarities to names. In all code files both SwiftUI and UIKit libraries are imported (even though the latter doesn't seem paramount for the compiler).

Many thanks for all contribution.

Comment: I don't know about #1, but for #1 you need to do `MoonView().snapshot(MoonView)` (MoonView needs to be instantiated). Or `let image = self.snapshot()` inside your `MoonView`.

Comment: If `MoonView().snapshot(MoonView)` is used then I get the same error as in #2. When `let image = self.snapshot()` is initiated then I have build errors that watchOS Extension compiler does not have `snapshot()` extension defined (*Value of type 'MoonView' has no member 'snapshot'*).

Comment: Ahhh sorry I made so many mistakes in the above comment. I meant for **#2** you need to do `MoonView().snapshot()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following extension:

```
extension View {
  func sayHello() {
    print("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

In order to achieve #1, you would put the extension in its own file and then assign it to each target where it will be used.

Then, as @aheze points out in the comments, you would have to call that function on an instance of a View (not a View type itself). So:

```
MoonView().sayHello()
```

However, in your case, the reason that you're seeing the error (like `Cannot find UIHostingController` in scope) is because `UIHostingController` and `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` are not available on WatchOS (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer), meaning the extension, as written, will not compile on that platform.

Comment: Is there then a way to walk around this limitation? For example first generate the UIImage and then somehow overlay such generated static UIImage into watchOS code?

Comment: Sure, you can definitely use a static UIImage in watchOS

Comment: Yeah, but I meant defining a constant UIImage in a file that has access to `snapshot()` extension and then using the same constant in a watchOS code file that cannot directly access said extension?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not clear on exactly what that means. If you need `snapshot` (as written), it can't be used at all on `watchOS` -- it doesn't matter what 'file' it's in. You could generate it on iOS and then send it to the watch (much bigger project).

Comment: That what I meant, thanks a lot for helping out. The primary problem was that I didn't realise that `UIHostingController` and `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` are just not available on watchOS. Will need to figure something else for that then